# What's react-scripts Jest default serializer for snapshot testing?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, create-react-app, react-scripts

The only information I've found is in [this link](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#configuration):

> The default Jest coverage configuration can be overriden by adding any of the following supported keys to a Jest config in your package.json.
>
> Supported overrides:
>
> - collectCoverageFrom
> - coverageReporters
> - coverageThreshold
> - snapshotSerializers

Inside my `node_modules/react-scripts/utils/createJestConfig.js`, the jest config object doesn't have a `snapshotSerializers` default property. I didn't find information about this anywhere else in the CRA's user guide, nor in the closed issues.

What's the default serializer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the `jest-snapshot` module to confirm the same. Jest uses this module for everything related to snapshot from serializing to snapshot assertions.

There is a module: `pretty-format` in jest packages from which Jest imports default serializers for React Elements, HTML elements, mock functions, JS built-in types, etc.

Code blob where `jest-snapshot` adds default serializers: https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/master/packages/jest-snapshot/src/plugins.js

`pretty-format` docs: https://github.com/facebook/jest/tree/master/packages/pretty-format